# windows10 crashed with error code 0x000000d1

Tags: bsod, windows-10

I have problem with windows 10.

There is some information about my crash.

1. The error code is 0x000000d1
2. I have update nvdia's newest drive.
3. The computer has told me it caused by `NETIO.SYS`.

Crash dump: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAED235CC8E19991!832&authkey=!AAbcN5ylhURHPWY&ithint=file%2cdmp

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx—can you pull up the error logs to see where the error occurred? Also, try posting the most recent file in `C:\Windows\Minidump` so that we can analyze it.

Comment: @DragonLord I got a message "Can't open file xxx" when I try to open the *.dump file

Comment: Try elevating to administrator permissions first.

Comment: @DragonLord How can I open it. I only get some messy code.

Comment: Just post the file online using a service such as OneDrive (built into Windows 10), and put up the sharing link so that we can download the file.

Comment: @DragonLord Fine, please wait a minute.

Comment: @DragonLord https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAED235CC8E19991!832&authkey=!AAbcN5ylhURHPWY&ithint=file%2cdmp

Comment: For some reason, the dump is making my debugger lock up. I'm downloading the Windows 10 version of WinDbg right now, so I'll be back with more information.

Comment: @DragonLord How about it?

Comment: See my answer. I've traced the problem to a program called Lantern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash seams to be caused by `epfwwfp.sys` which is part of ESET Smart security or the driver `netactmonitor.sys`

```
               rsp : 0xffffd00025f04de8 : 0xfffff80151965ba9 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
0xffffd00025f04de8 : 0xfffff80151965ba9 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
0xffffd00025f04e10 : 0xfffff801d57ddfb8 : NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+0x60
Unable to load image epfwwfp.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for epfwwfp.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for epfwwfp.sys
0xffffd00025f04f28 : 0xfffff801519643c8 : nt!KiPageFault+0x248
0xffffd00025f04f30 : 0x0000000000000000 :  Trap @ ffffd00025f04f30
0xffffd00025f04f50 : 0xfffff801d5831000 : NETIO!WPP_GLOBAL_Control
Unable to load image netactmonitor.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for netactmonitor.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for netactmonitor.sys
0xffffd00025f05050 : 0xfffff801d5831000 : NETIO!WPP_GLOBAL_Control
0xffffd00025f05098 : 0xfffff801d57ddfb8 : NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+0x60
0xffffd00025f05110 : 0xfffff801d5831002 : NETIO!WPP_GLOBAL_Control+0x2
0xffffd00025f05118 : 0xfffff801d57de60f : NETIO!StreamHandleDataClassify+0x133
```

Both are 1 year old and should be updated to a Win10 compatible version:

```
Image name: epfwwfp.sys
Timestamp:        Thu Sep 11 18:06:07 2014 (5411C86F)

Image path: netactmonitor.sys
Timestamp:        Fri Oct 10 09:17:23 2014
```

Comment: You might BOLD the error line in your bugcheck output. I believe your debugging analysis is correct, not caused by lantern.

Comment: @Moab afaik, I can't bold text in Code formatting.

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion? I'm not great with WinDbg and I must have missed something between some of the function calls in the stack trace.

Comment: @DragonLord I dumped some other data with dds/dqs similar to what Mark did here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/06/01/3335060.aspx

Comment: The ESET Smart security has a win10 compatible version?

Comment: version **8.0.319.0** seams to be Win10 compatible: http://www.eset.com/int/download/home/detail/family/5/ **Added: Compatibility with Microsoft Windows 10 RTM build 10240**

Answer (score 1):

### Note: This answer is incorrect and is retained for reference. Please see the answer by magicandre1981.

---

#### The system crashed in `NETIO.SYS` while running [Lantern](https://getlantern.org/), an Internet proxy tool.

- It appears that the networking subsystem malfunctioned while performing some network operation. The application running at the time was **[Lantern](https://getlantern.org/)** (`flashlight.exe`). There may be a bug in the application or in the networking driver; you may want to update Lantern when a new version becomes available.
- The bugcheck analysis is as follows:

  ```
  Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10240.9 X86
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


  Loading Dump File [E:\081115-9609-01.dmp]
  Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


  ************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
  Response                         Time (ms)     Location
  Deferred                                       SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
  Symbol search path is: SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
  Executable search path is: 
  No .natvis files found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\Visualizers.
  Windows 10 Kernel Version 10240 MP (4 procs) Free x64
  Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
  Built by: 10240.16412.amd64fre.th1.150729-1800
  Machine Name:
  Kernel base = 0xfffff801`5180e000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`51b33030
  Debug session time: Mon Aug 10 12:08:09.241 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
  System Uptime: 0 days 10:20:19.004
  Loading Kernel Symbols
  .

  Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
  Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

  ..............................................................
  ................................................................
  .........................................................
  Loading User Symbols
  Loading unloaded module list
  ....................
  *******************************************************************************
  *                                                                             *
  *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
  *                                                                             *
  *******************************************************************************

  Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

  BugCheck D1, {8, 2, 0, fffff801d57ddfb8}

  Probably caused by : NETIO.SYS ( NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+60 )

  Followup:     MachineOwner
  ---------

  1: kd> !analyze -v
  *******************************************************************************
  *                                                                             *
  *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
  *                                                                             *
  *******************************************************************************

  DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
  An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
  interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
  caused by drivers using improper addresses.
  If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
  Arguments:
  Arg1: 0000000000000008, memory referenced
  Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
  Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
  Arg4: fffff801d57ddfb8, address which referenced memory

  Debugging Details:
  ------------------


  SYSTEM_SKU:  All

  SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

  BIOS_DATE:  08/19/2014

  BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  B85-PRO GAMER

  BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

  DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x8
    Kernel Generated Triage Dump

  BUGCHECK_P1: 8

  BUGCHECK_P2: 2

  BUGCHECK_P3: 0

  BUGCHECK_P4: fffff801d57ddfb8

  READ_ADDRESS: fffff80151bd2500: Unable to get MiVisibleState
   0000000000000008 

  CURRENT_IRQL:  2

  FAULTING_IP: 
  NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+60
  fffff801`d57ddfb8 488b7008        mov     rsi,qword ptr [rax+8]

  CPU_COUNT: 4

  CPU_MHZ: ce4

  CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

  CPU_FAMILY: 6

  CPU_MODEL: 3c

  CPU_STEPPING: 3

  CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

  BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

  PROCESS_NAME:  flashlight.exe

  ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 x86fre

  TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd00025f04f30 -- (.trap 0xffffd00025f04f30)
  NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
  Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
  rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffd00025f05120
  rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
  rip=fffff801d57ddfb8 rsp=ffffd00025f050c0 rbp=ffffd00025f05149
   r8=0000000000000040  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000006
  r11=ffffe000afbdc9d0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
  r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
  iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
  NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+0x60:
  fffff801`d57ddfb8 488b7008        mov     rsi,qword ptr [rax+8] ds:00000000`00000008=????????????????
  Resetting default scope

  LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80151965ba9 to fffff8015195b220

  STACK_TEXT:  
  ffffd000`25f04de8 fffff801`51965ba9 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
  ffffd000`25f04df0 fffff801`519643c8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000004 00222d29`88000012 ae840200`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
  ffffd000`25f04f30 fffff801`d57ddfb8 : ffffe000`afbdcaa0 ffffd000`25f05149 ffffd000`25f05220 ffffe000`afbdcaa0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x248
  ffffd000`25f050c0 fffff801`d57dde91 : ffffe000`ad50dd40 ffffe000`afbdc9d0 ffffd000`25f055b8 ffffd000`25f055b8 : NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+0x60
  ffffd000`25f051a0 fffff801`d57db555 : ffffe000`a6b00014 fffff801`d7792528 ffffe000`00000001 ffffd000`25f05ca8 : NETIO!StreamProcessCallout+0x711
  ffffd000`25f052e0 fffff801`d57da434 : 00000000`00000014 ffffd000`25f05ca8 ffffe000`abfcd5a0 ffffd000`25f05b60 : NETIO!ProcessCallout+0x685
  ffffd000`25f05450 fffff801`d57d8f5e : 1bff4aa0`cc49f9c1 ffffd000`25f05740 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`aab26440 : NETIO!ArbitrateAndEnforce+0x494
  ffffd000`25f05640 fffff801`d57d8890 : ffffe000`ac675dc0 ffffd000`25f05bb0 ffffd000`25f05bb0 ffffe000`b13898d0 : NETIO!KfdClassify+0x32e
  ffffd000`25f05ab0 fffff801`d57d8528 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : NETIO!StreamClassify+0x268
  ffffd000`25f05c50 fffff801`d57d69f4 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`b0002e10 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : NETIO!StreamCommonInspect+0x244
  ffffd000`25f05ff0 fffff801`d5899fd5 : ffffe000`b13898d0 ffffd000`25f06360 ffffd000`25f060e1 00000000`00000000 : NETIO!WfpStreamInspectSend+0x264
  ffffd000`25f06080 fffff801`d589992b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`25f06b01 fffff801`5188a331 : tcpip!TcpEnqueueTcbSend+0x4f5
  ffffd000`25f06180 fffff801`5188a2b5 : ffffd000`25f06b01 ffffd000`25f06280 ffffd000`25f066c0 fffff801`d5899900 : tcpip!TcpTlConnectionSendCalloutRoutine+0x2b
  ffffd000`25f06200 fffff801`d58e4022 : ffffe000`addc5e20 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffe000`a6b3b450 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal+0x85
  ffffd000`25f06250 fffff801`d51ee1c7 : ffffe000`addc5e20 ffffd000`25f06b80 00000000`0000002d 00000000`0000002d : tcpip!TcpTlConnectionSend+0x72
  ffffd000`25f062c0 fffff801`d51d07b3 : ffffe000`ab82f010 00000000`00000000 00000000`3296fd38 fffff801`51a80297 : afd!AfdFastConnectionSend+0x387
  ffffd000`25f06480 fffff801`51c3be83 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff801`51857012 : afd!AfdFastIoDeviceControl+0x863
  ffffd000`25f06800 fffff801`51c3ba56 : ffffe000`acc78fe0 ffffe000`acc78fe0 00000000`00000001 00000000`1374a324 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x423
  ffffd000`25f06a20 fffff801`51965863 : 00000000`7fe91000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff801`51c394ac : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
  ffffd000`25f06a90 00000000`545a1e52 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
  00000000`3294f3c8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x545a1e52


  STACK_COMMAND:  kb

  FOLLOWUP_IP: 
  NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+60
  fffff801`d57ddfb8 488b7008        mov     rsi,qword ptr [rax+8]

  SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

  SYMBOL_NAME:  NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction+60

  FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

  MODULE_NAME: NETIO

  IMAGE_NAME:  NETIO.SYS

  DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  559f3890

  IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

  BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  60

  FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction

  BUCKET_ID:  AV_NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction

  PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  AV_NETIO!StreamInvokeCalloutAndNormalizeAction

  ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

  FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:av_netio!streaminvokecalloutandnormalizeaction

  FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c2ca2d1f-cfdc-88d5-c7bc-7693b8f0de04}

  Followup:     MachineOwner
  ---------
  ```

Comment: I see. Can I fix it by updading lantern?

Comment: I'd give it a shot. A newer version might have fixed a relevant bug. If that doesn't help, the problem may be a bug in the OS itself.

Comment: Lantern fixed it ?

Comment: I don't know. Try installing the most recent version.

Answer (score -1):

This BSOD is caused by a corrupted or unstable driver or program. Try rolling back the newest driver you installed.

EDIT:
The program appears to be Lantern, which is a proxy. It had a error while performing. A network operation.

Comment: Can you tell me which driver is unstable?

Comment: I would need the .sys filename

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAED235CC8E19991!832&authkey=!AAbcN5ylhURHPWY&ithint=file%2cdmp

Comment: I mean the .sys file that you saw in the bsod @WhiteWater

Comment: @WhiteWater if you cannot find it, ill try to analyze the MiniDump file

Comment: Probably caused by : NETIO.SYS ( NETIO+dfb8 )

Comment: @WhiteWater it appears to be caused by an exe named `flashlight.exe`

Comment: What's this?I have no idea about it.

Comment: @WhiteWater In the trace, it shows that the crash came from a process using the network.

Comment: I have no app named flashlight.exe

Comment: @WhiteWater: `flashlight.exe` is [Lantern](https://getlantern.org/).

Comment: It should be flashlight which use network?

Comment: Yeah, I have lantern.

Comment: Here is the full dump:http://pastebin.com/UwePcLwJ

Comment: Can I fix it ? without unintalling lantern.

Comment: @WhiteWater I can't figure that out right now, I don't have my windows computer with me, sorry.

Comment: Can I check two answers right?

Comment: No, you cannot check 2 answers.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad, I'll give it to @DragonLord, he is the first man to answer my question. So sorry about it.

Comment: @WhiteWater Its okay