# BSOD - Windows 10 Bad Pool Caller when browsing internet (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bsod

Struggling with this problem for two months now. Updated BIOS to newest version and it still happens (less often). I have no idea how to analyse minidump file...

Just in case it means something - bad pool caller occurs (100%) when downloading Filezilla.

Here is my rig:
i7-7700K 4.2Ghz
GTX 1070 Gigabyte G1 
Gigabyte Gaming K5 (BIOS version F7)
Corsair Vengeance LED 16GB (CMU16GX4M2C3200C16)
Creative Sound Blaster ZR

Minidump file:

```
    BAD_POOL_CALLER (c2)
The current thread is making a bad pool request.  Typically this is at a bad IRQL level or double freeing the same allocation, etc.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000010, type of pool violation the caller is guilty of.
Arg2: ffff8f85941ee288
Arg3: 000000008f1f9100
Arg4: ffff8f85941ee2b0

Debugging Details:
------------------


FAULTING_IP: 
NETIO!NetioFreeMdl+136e8
fffff80b`b95b7d98 90              nop

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc2_10

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8016de82097 to fffff8016dd6d560

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffa680`105ac478 fffff801`6de82097 : 00000000`000000c2 00000000`00000010 ffff8f85`941ee288 00000000`8f1f9100 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffa680`105ac480 fffff80b`b95b7d98 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 ffff8f85`957ed390 00000000`00000001 : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x1077
ffffa680`105ac580 fffff80b`b9ab27f9 : 00000000`00000000 ffff8f85`93d739f0 ffff8f85`91737be0 ffff8f85`93d73880 : NETIO!NetioFreeMdl+0x136e8
ffffa680`105ac5d0 fffff80b`b95817d5 : ffff8f85`93d73880 ffff8f85`93b926d1 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : fwpkclnt!FwppInjectComplete+0x59
ffffa680`105ac610 fffff80b`b95816b9 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8f85`91e14b00 : NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferList+0xa5
ffffa680`105ac650 fffff80b`b98096d9 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffff801`6e48f618 : NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferListChain+0x289
ffffa680`105ac6d0 fffff80b`b9441d36 : 00000000`00000001 ffffa680`105ac769 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : tcpip!FlSendNetBufferListChainComplete+0x59
ffffa680`105ac700 fffff80b`b9441b03 : ffff8f85`8f5d4100 ffff8f85`91e14b02 ffff8f85`00000001 ffff8f85`91e14b01 : ndis!ndisMSendCompleteNetBufferListsInternal+0x136
ffffa680`105ac7d0 fffff80b`bee2892d : ffff8f85`8f5d41a0 ffff8f85`8f482a20 ffff8f85`8f482000 fffff80b`bee29702 : ndis!NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x213
ffffa680`105ac8c0 ffff8f85`8f5d41a0 : ffff8f85`8f482a20 ffff8f85`8f482000 fffff80b`bee29702 ffff8f85`90123e18 : e2xw10x64+0x892d
ffffa680`105ac8c8 ffff8f85`8f482a20 : ffff8f85`8f482000 fffff80b`bee29702 ffff8f85`90123e18 ffff8f85`90123e18 : 0xffff8f85`8f5d41a0
ffffa680`105ac8d0 ffff8f85`8f482000 : fffff80b`bee29702 ffff8f85`90123e18 ffff8f85`90123e18 00000000`00000000 : 0xffff8f85`8f482a20
ffffa680`105ac8d8 fffff80b`bee29702 : ffff8f85`90123e18 ffff8f85`90123e18 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xffff8f85`8f482000
ffffa680`105ac8e0 ffff8f85`90123e18 : ffff8f85`90123e18 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : e2xw10x64+0x9702
ffffa680`105ac8e8 ffff8f85`90123e18 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xffff8f85`90123e18
ffffa680`105ac8f0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00008000 : 0xffff8f85`90123e18


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
NETIO!NetioFreeMdl+136e8
fffff80b`b95b7d98 90              nop

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  NETIO!NetioFreeMdl+136e8

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: NETIO

IMAGE_NAME:  NETIO.SYS

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  2f813bef

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.15063.468

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  136e8

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  OLD_IMAGE_NETIO.SYS

BUCKET_ID:  OLD_IMAGE_NETIO.SYS

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:old_image_netio.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {248567a9-afbb-75e2-4d3a-e2178362efb0}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: NETIO.SYS Update your LAN or Wireless network adapter adapter driver

Comment: UPDATED - will see soon enough if it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/955379/windows10-crashed-with-error-code-0x000000d1 If you want specifics then use windbg and submit the analysis logs

Comment: As per: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc2--bad-pool-caller.  I would suggest enabling driver verifier.  This will most likely get you a stack/module which caused the problem.

Comment: @HelpingHand did that - didnt work at all. Caused more problems than bsod it self..

Comment: Well it should still BSOD but the hope is the dump is more informative.  What problems did it cause? Did you select all drivers, that could cause issues?  I would probably start with just non-Microsoft ones.

Comment: e2xw10x64 = killer LAN driver, so Ramhound is right, update the driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  NETIO.SYS Update your LAN or Wireless network adapter adapter driver
> ```

After month of testing and trying to crash it, I am happy to say that network adapter driver update WORKED!

All thanks to Ramhound.